# Azure Blob Trigger. Configure Blob Path in Configuration Files

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using Blob trigger in my project to process the content of files.

I am using Azure Blob Trigger to initiate the process of a file execution.

```
[FunctionName("FunctionImportCatalogue")]
public static void Run([BlobTrigger("importcontainer/{name}", Connection = "StorageConnection")]Stream myBlob, string name, TraceWriter log)
{}
```

Depending on where the code is published the blobcontainer should change accordingly. I mean I want the "importcontainer" to be configured in config files. Can I do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As far as I know, you could configure it in the `local.settings.json`.
Add the code below to the `Values` in the file, my sample container named 'workitems'.

```
"importcontainer": "workitems"
```

Then change the code below in the .cs file.

```
public static void Run([BlobTrigger("%importcontainer%/{name}", Connection = "StorageConnection")]Stream myBlob, string name, TraceWriter log)
```

Then publish the Function to Azure, you should set `importcontainer` in the **Application settings** in the portal like screenshot below, because the setting will be used.

[image]

Run the function and add a blob to the container, it works fine on my side.

[image]

Comment: Works a treat, thanks.